# Pegar o retorno de um método WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho o seguinte código é quero pegar um retorno na variável resultado se for verdadeiro ou falso, como eu poderia fazer isso?

```cs
//http://localhost:1608/api/ApiCidade/deletar/cliente/10
[HttpDelete]
[Route("deletar/cliente/{id:int}")]
public HttpResponseMessage ClienteDeletar(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var resultado = true;
        var tCliente = new ClienteAplicacao();
        tCliente.Excluir(id);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Na Aplicação eu tenho:

```cs
public void Excluir(int id)
{
    var strQuery = string.Format("DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id= {0}", id);
    using (contexto = new Contexto())
    {
        contexto.ExecutaComando(strQuery);                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer.

Comment: esta duplicado [ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96643/como-retornar-consulta-por-uma-string-usando-webapi]

Comment: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96643/como-retornar-consulta-por-uma-string-usando-webapi]

Comment: E qual seria o critério para `true` ou `false`? Retorno de onde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vi, você está utilizando [esse modelo](https://github.com/cleytonferrari/PadraoDeRepositorio/tree/master/TISelvagem) pra desenvolver sua API.

Você tem que retornar `true` ou `false` no método excluir, para isso fiz algumas modificações no seu código, da uma olhada:

```
public bool Excluir(int id)
{
    var retorno = 0;
    var strQuery = string.Format("DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id= {0}; SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE id = {0}", id);
    using (contexto = new Contexto())
    {
        var reader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
        while (reader.Read()) {
            retorno = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    if (retorno == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

E na sua API, você vai armazenar o valor do retorno:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("deletar/cliente/{id:int}")]
public HttpResponseMessage ClienteDeletar(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var tCliente = new ClienteAplicacao();
        var resultado = tCliente.Excluir(id);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

A ideia seria verificar se o registro com esse id existe logo após a exclusão.
Não testei o exemplo, mas a ideia seria algo assim.

Comment: Correto, era isso mesmo que precisava!! agradeço