# Como retornar consulta por uma string usando WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho o seguinte código que me gera um erro:

> The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'String'.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'String'.

```
        //http://localhost:1608/api/ApiCidade/consulta/clienteLoginSenha/
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("consulta/clienteLoginSenha/{email:long};{senha:long}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ClientePorLoginSenha(string email, string senha)
        {
            try
            {
                var tCliente = new ClienteAplicacao();
                var listarDeClientes = tCliente.ListarPorLoginSenha(email,senha);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listarDeClientes.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }





//http://localhost:1608/api/ApiCidade/consulta/clientePorNome/e
[HttpGet]
[Route("consulta/clientePorNome/{nome:String}")]
public HttpResponseMessage ClientePorNome(string nome)
{
    try
    {
        var tCliente = new ClienteAplicacao();
        var listarDeClientes = tCliente.ListarPorNome(nome);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listarDeClientes.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

consulta que está na aplicação :

```html
        public List<Cliente> ListarPorNome(string nome)
        {
            var strQuery = string.Format("select * from clientes where nome like {0}", nome + '%');

            using (contexto = new Contexto())
            {
                var retornoDataReader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                return TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(retornoDataReader);
            }

        }


     private List<Cliente> TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            var clientes = new List<Cliente>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                Cliente cliente = new Cliente()
                {
                    Id = reader["id"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                    Nome = reader["nome"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["nome"].ToString(),
                    DataNascimento = reader["data_nascimento"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["data_nascimento"]),
                    Email = reader["email"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["email"].ToString()

                };

                clientes.Add(cliente);
            }
            reader.Close();
            return clientes;
        }
```

Comment: Que tipo o método **ListarPorNome** (_tCliente.ListarPorNome(nome);_) retorna? Quando eu utilizo, eu retorno diretamente a lista (List<T>).

Comment: Adicionei o código mais completo, veja se pode me ajudar

Comment: Acho que você não precisa converter para array (listarDeClientes.ToArray()) pois já é uma lista. Já tentou retornar somente a lista?

Comment: minha dúvida está nesta linha:[Route("consulta/clientePorNome/{nome:String}")] não consigo usar desta forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `:String` não é uma constraint válida para configuração da rota. Segue abaixo link de constraints permitidas para a configuração de rota. Verifique se sem esta constraint o seu código continua a levantar este erro.

```
{ "bool", typeof(BoolRouteConstraint) },
{ "datetime", typeof(DateTimeRouteConstraint) },
{ "decimal", typeof(DecimalRouteConstraint) },
{ "double", typeof(DoubleRouteConstraint) },
{ "float", typeof(FloatRouteConstraint) },
{ "guid", typeof(GuidRouteConstraint) },
{ "int", typeof(IntRouteConstraint) },
{ "long", typeof(LongRouteConstraint) },

// Length constraints
{ "minlength", typeof(MinLengthRouteConstraint) },
{ "maxlength", typeof(MaxLengthRouteConstraint) },
{ "length", typeof(LengthRouteConstraint) },

// Min/Max value constraints
{ "min", typeof(MinRouteConstraint) },
{ "max", typeof(MaxRouteConstraint) },
{ "range", typeof(RangeRouteConstraint) },

// Regex-based constraints
{ "alpha", typeof(AlphaRouteConstraint) },
{ "regex", typeof(RegexRouteConstraint) }
```

Você pode utilizar o `AlphaRouteConstraint` para restringir o parâmetro para conter apenas letras do alfabeto latino **A-Z**, incluindo letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Exemplo:

```
[Route("consulta/clientePorNome/{nome:alpha}")]
```

Fontes:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412021/defaultinlinecontraintresolver-error-in-webapi-2
>
> http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

Comment: correto, o problema era isso, apos usar o nome:alpha deu tudo certo

Comment: Perfeito. Comente caso surja alguma necessidade de esclarecimento

Comment: Quando eu preciso enviar uma rota com 2 informações :
[Route("consulta/clienteLoginSenha/{email:long};{senha:long}")]
como ficaria? agradeço,

Comment: [Route("consulta/clienteLoginSenha/{email:long}/{senha:long}")], contudo, esta é uma resposta para outra pergunta. Sugiro marcar esta como respondida e criar uma outra para esta questão. Verifique se ela não existe antes para não criar uma pergunta duplicada.